# Java Regex Example

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I want to use regex in java. However my code is printing *false* and I want to know what is wrong with my code because I want to print *true* to procede my logic.

CODE:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher
import java.util.regex.Pattern

def input = "/[ANY]/Java/Groovy*/Test"
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("Groovy(.*?)\$"))
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input)
println(matcher.find())
```

Comment: ... and called quote around the regexp

Comment: I did not understant what you meant

Comment: @cfrick i did't even see that :D good catch

Comment: @f1sh escaping the `$` is not a problem, since it's not in *regex* it's a *string*. The string literal `"\$"` produces a string with content `$` *not* a string with content `\$`. It's that string content then that gets fed into the regex interpreter.

Comment: Hmm but removing the escape or comletly remove `\$` does not seem to solve things for me at least. https://onecompiler.com/java/3vgvv78f6

Comment: @RafaelFerreira [`Pattern.quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) produces a raw version of the input, so when you compile it you'd get a *literal match* against it. In other words if you do `Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(".*"))` you will not match "any input" but *literally* only the input `.*`

Comment: @Eraklon because the pattern is still interpreted as literal?

Comment: @VLAZ Yep, your answer answered it. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @VLAZ. The answer is:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      String input = "/[ANY]/Java/Groovy*/Test";
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Groovy(.*?)$");
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
      System.out.println(matcher.find());
    }
}
```

Comment: Or "groovy": `("/[ANY]/Java/Groovy*/Test" =~ "Groovy(.*?)\$").find()`

Comment: I find the "javafication" of the answer quite questionable.  The question is groovy and some folks even tripped over the `$`-problem.  I'd rather remove the [java]...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you use [`Pattern.quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) when building the pattern. That method produces a raw version of the pattern that will match literally. In other words

```java
Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(".*"))
```

Will not match "any input" but literally only the input that consists of a dot and an asterisk: `.*`

Just remove that call and leave `Pattern.compile("Groovy(.*?)$")`.

[Runnable example](https://onecompiler.com/java/3vgvwnd6d)

You can also drop the escaping of `$` in the string, as it's not needed. In a string literal, the sequence `\$` produces the content `$`, which is the same as just using `$` in the first place. It's *that* content that is used by the regex engine to determine what the pattern means. So if you *do* want to escape a symbol *for the regex engine*, you need to escape it twice

1. For the string, so a string literal `"\\$"` produces content of `\$`
2. For the regex engine which will consume the content `\$` and determine it's a literal `$`, not the end of line special character.

Also, as Wiktor Stribiżew [pointed out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60165296/java-regex-example/60165797#comment106415830_60165797) there is no need for the `?` to induce lazy matching. Using `Pattern.compile("Groovy(.*)")` would be enough.

Comment: Use `Groovy(.*)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah, I guess there is no need for the lazy behaviour here.